# using zend with oracle ORA-00911: invalid character

Tags: zend-framework, oracle11g

```
        ORA-00911: invalid character SELECT "SCORES"."SUBSCRIBERID" AS
     "subscriberId", SUM(SCORES.SCORE) AS "SCORE", "SUBSCRIBERS"."SUBSCRIBERID",
     "SUBSCRIBERS"."FIRSTNAME", "SUBSCRIBERS"."LASTNAME",
 "SUBSCRIBERS"."MOBILE" FROM "SCORES" INNER JOIN "SUBSCRIBERS" ON
"SUBSCRIBERS"."SUBSCRIBERID"="SCORES"."SUBSCRIBERID" WHERE ("SCORES"."POLLINGID"=2) AND ("SUBSCRIBERS"."SUBSCRIBERID" 
not in (SELECT "POLLING_TRIALAUDIENCE_SUBSCRIB"."SUBSCRIBERID" FROM "POLLING_TRIALAUDIENCE_SUBSCRIB" WHERE 
        ("POLLING_TRIALAUDIENCE_SUBSCRIB"."POLLINGID"=2))) AND 
        ("SUBSCRIBERS"."SUBSCRIBERID" not in (SELECT 
        "GROUP_SUBSCRIBERS"."SUBSCRIBERID" FROM "POLLING_TRIALAUDIENCE_GROUPS" INNER
         JOIN "GROUP_SUBSCRIBERS" ON 
        "POLLING_TRIALAUDIENCE_GROUPS"."GROUPID"="GROUP_SUBSCRIBERS"."GROUPID" WHERE
         ("POLLINGID"=2))) GROUP BY "SUBSCRIBERS"."SUBSCRIBERID" HAVING (SCORE *in (
         select * from(SELECT distinct sum("SCORES"."SCORE") TopScore FROM 
        `"SCORES"` WHERE "SCORES"."POLLINGID"=2 group by "SCORES"."SUBSCRIBERID"
         order by TopScore desc limit 100) as t)) ORDER BY "SCORE" DESC
```

please help me!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the asterisk in `HAVING (SCORE *in (` isn't really there, as that would generate "ORA-00936: missing expression", the first problem in what you posted is the backticks you have around `"SCORES"`. It's possible you've introduced those while creating the question too of course, but they would generate "ORA-00911: invalid character if they are present".

You have other problems too; `limit` isn't supported by Oracle, you can't use `AS` for a table alias (`as t` after the limit), you have non-aggregate columns in the select list that are no in your group-by clause, ... probably other things too once those are resolved.